# Set java version to two different Tomcat instances

Tags: java, tomcat

I've two Tomcat instances A and B on my working machine and I need to set two different java versions for each instance; on A java 1.6 and on B java 1.7, how can I make it?

Comment: In catlina.bat file, set JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change `JAVA_HOME` to the explicit path of your java installation in `tomcat\bin\catalina.bat`
for windows or `tomcat\bin\catalina.sh` for linux

for java7 the path could be `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`

Answer (score 3):

In catalina.bat file, set JAVA_HOME for both instances of tomcat.
say for instance A, set it to path of java 1.6 and for instance B , set it as java 1.7.

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07
```

add this line in the bat file, change path accordingly.